# Find in hash and remove in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a method that is given a particular options hash like this

```
def send_params(options = {})
 #Create string of some values in the hash.
end
```

I want to create a string with some of the values are in the hash. Particularly I am looking for the keys :key1, :key2, :key3, :key4 to create a string with their correspondent values.  So, if my hash is like this:

```
{:key1 => 'value1', :key2 => 'value2', :key3 => 'value3', :key4 => 'value4', , :key5 => 'value5'}
```

I want to be able to create a string like:

```
'value1,value2|value3,value4'
```

And have the remaining hash as:

```
{:key5 => 'value5'}
```

So, the values that are found should be deleted from the hash.  What is a good way of doing so?

Comment: It's confusing to me what you're asking. You say you want to create a string with some of the keys in a hash, but then the example string you give only contains values that are in the hash. Also, it's unclear what the meaning of the pipe (`|`) is in your string.

Comment: Sorry. I meant with the values. The pipe is just supposed to be in the string, it's just another character.  I wonder why the downvote.

Comment: Both too trivial and too localized.

Comment: @meagar What do you mean by too trivial? Who decides what's trivial?

Comment: The community does. There is nothing here but fundamental Ruby syntax. There is nothing that should stump anybody with a grasp of Ruby, nothing you shouldn't be able to figure out yourself through a modicum of research. You're just asking for the specific line of code to be written for you. A line of code that is useful for you, and nobody else, and is never likely to be useful again. That's too localized (by definition) and incredibly trivial. There is no problem to solve here, just a line of code to be written.

Comment: @meagar I am sorry I made it look that way. I guess I wanted to know a method that could let me find, extract and delete a key/value in a hash. The string part is useless, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Hash#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete) may be what you are looking for.
It will remove a key/value pair from a hash and return the value.

Example:

```
h = {
  :key1 => 'value1',
  :key2 => 'value2',
  :key3 => 'value3',
  :key4 => 'value4',
  :key5 => 'value5'
}
str = "#{h.delete :key1},#{h.delete :key2}|#{h.delete :key3},#{h.delete :key4}"
p str # => "value1,value2|value3,value4" 
p h   # => {:key5=>"value5"}
```